# Making devise alerts dismissible - syntax error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am trying to have my devise alerts be dismissible.  data-dismiss="alert" is what I believe is required, per the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts

However, I try to add this into my application layout per the below, and I receive a syntax error:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}", data-dismiss: "alert") %>
<% end %>
```

Without the data-dismiss the code works fine, but is not dismissable.

Here is the syntax error:

```
...rt alert-#{key}", data-dismiss: "alert") );@output_buffer.sa...
...                               ^
```

The point of data-dismiss: "alert" is to have it closable with an X as per bootstrap buttons.  This involves including an "X" button, how do I fix the syntax error and include the "X"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable and option names cannot have hyphens in them like that.

Try using the `data` option instead:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}", data: { dismiss: "alert" }) %>
```

Here is a little `rails c` example of using `data`:

```
2.0.0p247 :006 > content_tag :p, 'Foo', data: { test: 'bar' }
 => "<p data-test=\"bar\">Foo</p>"
```

**Update** If you want to get it to work fully based on what's prescribed on in the Bootstrap docs, try this:

```
<% flash.except(:timedout).each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{key}", data: { dismiss: "alert" } do %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that worked, but there is no "x" - do you know how I can also put an "x" on the right side, as in bootstrap's example, within my code?

Comment: @SeanL Look at the `<button>` markup that should be there on this page: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts

Comment: Yes, but if I just do this: <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> <% end %>  the button appears below the bar, because it is not within the content tag - I guess I am trying to figure out how to get that button within the content tag

Comment: @SeanL Well, I answered your question, which was how to get rid of the error. But I updated my answer to demonstrate one way of getting the results that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I also adjusted the question to your full answer to make it more valuable for future users.

Comment: @SeanL You're welcome. Good call on adjusting the question. One other note of experience: you may want to modify the `flash.each` call to exclude a key called `:timedout`, which I believe Devise sometimes adds in. I'll update my answer to include that logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}", :"data-dismiss" => "alert") %>
```

This should work